# Why is my view not displaying Solr index results?

Tags: views, search

I have a multilingual site and I created a Solr server, created an index (for all content types), added fields, generated the search (it displayed that all my nodes were succcessfully indexed 8/8), then created a view using that index and selected render entity and the view has no results. I tried fiddling about with every setting in the search_api options/index, rebuilding the index, clearing the cache, and the view results is always empty. Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was i forgot to look at the php-error log/watchdog. There was a custom module which had some code which was causing a fatal error on all links being generated. Fixed that issue, all was working after.